# Add files from three sub directories into their own Lists in C#

Tags: c#, file

I was wondering if there is any way to get the file names from three subdirectories into their own lists.  The File path is `Main->folder->subfolder` There are three folders and each folder has a subfolder i need the file names from.  Is there any way to do this? I currently have this code written to get a master list of all file names into a master list

```
public static List<String> DirectorySearch(string dir)
{
    List<String> ListFiles = new List<String>();
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
        {
            var GetFileName = Path.GetFileName(f);
            //Console.WriteLine(GetFileName);
            ListFiles.Add((GetFileName).ToString());
        }

        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
        {
            var GetDirName = Path.GetFileName(d);

            ListFiles.AddRange(DirectorySearch(d));
            ListFiles.Add((GetDirName).ToString());
        }                 
        return ListFiles;
    }
```

If it is a lot of code and too much to write please let me know and possibly point me in the right direction so i could figure out the rest for myself.  Any kind of advice is helpful!

Comment: So you want to get the directory, then enumerate through those sub directories for files?

Comment: @Greg yes, i need to enumerate through the sub directories to get 3 certain sub directories and get their file names and add them into a List or Array

Comment: You might also have a look at this SO answer: [How to read File names recursively from subfolder using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3768770/880990).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use following concise code using LINQ:

```
 List<string> ListFiles = Directory.GetDirectories(dir)
    .SelectMany(d => Directory.GetDirectories(d).SelectMany(Directory.EnumerateFiles))
    .ToList();
```

This returns all file-paths in the subfolder.

Comment: I'm very much a fan of linq, and this is an elegant answer.  I would add some explanation on why it works, since the OP appears to be a relatively new programmer and understanding linq can be hard

Comment: @MarshallTigerus Yes i am relatively new to programming so both of your answers were very useful! Thank you guys very much.

Comment: @DylanT: well, does it work at all? I couldn't test it. It's hard to explain it without explaining whole LINQ. But if you have a specific question, ask.

Comment: Doesn't this return only the files from the deepest level of subdirectories? (I am not sure what the OP wants, but his example seems to return files of the top directory as well.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I have a main directory with 2 sub directories and each has another 3 sub directories.  So it goes `Main->sub directory->sub directory` and i need to get the file names from only 2 of the "sub sub directories" if that makes sense

Comment: @DylanT do you need only the files from the third level? Because that's what is returned from this query. I thought you only needed those

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes i only need third level but the part im having issues with is getting only certain folders from the third level.  I need the file names from 3 different folders in the third level, the folders are named "Activities" and from i need the names from each folder in their own individual Lists.

Comment: @DylanT: i still don't get what files or folders you need. Maybe you should provide an example in your question including filename and a desired result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Hey Tim, thank you for your help but i just figured out a way to do it.  I used the full pathway and created regular expressions for the folders i needed and retrieved the files! I appreciate you trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible.  Comments inline

```
/// By convention, it's better to use the primitive type string as opposed to the 
/// wrapping Type String except when making calls to the String static methods
public static Dictionary<string, List<string>> DirectorySearch(string dir)
    {
        /// I would define a dictionary<string, List<string>> to house the file names
        /// and folder names

        var fileDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        /// note: variables should be camel case to avoid confusion between them and
        /// classes or properties (which are Pascal Cased)
        try
        {
            var listFiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(dir))
            {
                listFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            }
            /// First, we add all the parent directory's files to the dictionary
            fileDictionary.Add(dir, listFiles);

            /// Then we iterate over the subdirectory and add those files to their
            /// own key in the fileDictionary
            foreach (string subDirectory in Directory.GetDirectories(dir))
            {
                listFiles = new List<string>();
                foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(subDirectory))
                {
                    listFiles.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
                }
                fileDictionary.Add(subDirectory, listFiles);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            /// Do something with your exception
        }
        return fileDictionary;
    }
```